# Is there such thing as a "loss of entropy" in random probability?

Tags: probability, random, entropy

A simple probability problem is to find a random number between 1 and 4 (inclusive) using a 6-sided fair dice. A simple solution would be to just roll the dice, and discard all 5's and 6's.

However, at a math talk, someone offhandedly mentioned that discarding the 5's and 6's would lead to a "loss in entropy", whatever that means...? By definition, the mentioned solution would still preserve the requirement of randomness; that is, all events are equally distributed. Then, is there any meaning to this "loss of entropy" that was, perhaps jokingly, mentioned?

Comment: Probabilities represent the frequency of occurrence of an event. The event is random as long as one cannot predict almost surely what will happen. That is, the event is random until it occurs. In your question, suppose we simulated 1000 values from 1 to 6 and threw out all the 5s and 6s we got. Using Bayes Rule, we will converge to $P(X=i)$ for $i \in [1,4]$ Perhaps it was a joke. Or they meant something completely different, such as if we do not directly observe the event, then who the hell knows what quantum mechanics says about tossing out the 5s and 6s. _I love rolling 3 sided dice_

Comment: You can look here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory), just before the Example section there is the definition of conditioned entropy, that is, obviously, less than the entropy of the conditioned event.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I suppose that in practice, as long as we still generate the same number of samples for whatever we are testing for, there is no difference. Perhaps it was a joke.

@N74 what's actually interesting is that in a real world situation, what the wikipedia article says makes sense. You can imagine a audience watching someone roll a dice 6 sided dice for 6 numbers. The results are probably boring. On the other hand, if he were to roll a 100 sided dice and discard 94 values to get a random number from 1-6, a valid roll would be psychologically more impactful.

Comment: Anyway entropy is valuable. With 4 rolls of your die you can generate 6 random numbers (in the range 1..4), discarding 5 and 6 you need more than one roll (on average) to generate a single sample. If a roll took 1s and you needed, say, 5400 numbers, you will wait one hour, deterministic, using all your entropy and two, on average, discarding undesired outcomes.